# Discord.py on_member_join not responding

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am using a `@client.event` function for my `on_member_join` event. I would like it to send a message upon a user joining, however, there are no responses nor errors from the console.

Here is my current attempted code

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send(
        "<a:welcome1:805857483473027122><a:welcome2:805857477375164468> \n<a:tysm:805858522578812930>"
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events related to members or `on_member_join` event, will require the special member intents to be enabled in the developer portal as well as defined in your code.

After enabling the intents in the `bot` section of the portal, copy this into your code to use the special `member_intents` module

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='Prefix', intents=intents)
```

Comment: i got an error message: `NameError: name 'intents' is not defined`

Comment: wait nvm sorry ;-;