# Sending welcome message in discord.py [@bot.event doesn't react?]

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm having some trouble making sure my bot sends a message when a user joins the server, my code seems to be alright, yet it doesn't send nor print anything

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config.PREFIX, case_insensitive=True)


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("a member joined")
    await bot.get_channel(851883872186400812).send(f"<@!{member.id}> just joined the server! Welcome and enjoy your stay!")



bot.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py on\_member\_join not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66039771/discord-py-on-member-join-not-responding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to open the "Members" intent. Go to http://discord.com/developers, select your bot and then open this in the "Bot" section: [image]

After doing that. You need to open intents in your code too. Its really simple.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config.PREFIX, case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
```